# How to set a player as default for whole FOLDERS in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: directory, default, video-player

The question does not aim at default for playing single files, but when wanting to select an entire folder with Ubuntu 22.04. Currently the only option is to 'open with other application' and then from there to select - 3 steps instead of 2, and I can't believe that there isn't a simple solution for this.
Ubuntu seems to change this randomly, I remember running into this before with another version, then with 16.04 no problem, right-click, there's my player.
Not the most urgent issue in the world right now, but it seems unnecessary.
Anyone? Thanks :)